# Create Win8.1 USB without WinUSB

Tags: apt, usb, windows-8

I am in need of creating a Windows 8.1 Pro USB bootable. I've tried googling for solutions and all returned `Winusb`. Upon installing `winusb`, these errors shows up on the CLI input `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Thus, when I enter this CLI input `sudo apt-get install winusb`, this message is shown `E: Unable to locate package winusb`.

I was wondering is there another way to install/create a Windows8.1 USB Bootable using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the source of the Windows installer is coming from an `.iso` file.

Comment: Because colingille didn't update his PPA for 14.04. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/381560/202806) comes the solution for this.

Comment: Oh, I see. So how could I create one then?

Comment: That ppa has not been updated for 14.04, but the software itself works in 14.04. You could edit the entry to check for `precise` instead of `trusty`. Use `software-properties-gtk` to edit the source entry and then do `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: In fact, given that winusb is likely to remain unchanged for a while, you could simply download the .deb file for winusb for any release from Launchpad and install it using the Software Centre.